# WP-Admin HTTP ERROR 500 After Moving wp-config.php up one level

Tags: php, wordpress, security

After moving my original wp-config up a level into the main directory, and calling that file inside of my old wp-config within the public_html directory with the following script, I can no longer access my wp-admin panel with (HTTP Error 500):

```
<?php
include('../wp-config.php');
?>
```

When returning the original wp-config.php content, the wp-admin is accessible again. I have tried to change all plugin names, remove .htaccess, etc. - But I think I am missing something. Permissions for wp-admin folder are 755

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Why would you move `wp-config.php` to any other place? Just keep it where it is.

Comment: https://www.groovypost.com/howto/improve-wordpress-securitty-wp-config-php-location/

Comment: Try using the full absolute path instead of a relative `..` path

Comment: aynber I am as happy as upset that this worked. The reason for using the ../ was my creative security brain (let's hide our username). I assume we just have to make the sacrifice here of having our username printed in the filepath - small sacrifice for big improvements nonetheless. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to hide the full path, you can use a relative path from DOCUMENT_ROOT. In either case, the file should not be accessible from a browser.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this please? I think I understand, but curious to see it explained thoroughly

Comment: `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../wp-config.php');` should work.

Comment: CONFIRMED - Working; thank you!